# How can I save my table with its column headers in csv?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm not able to have my table out properly., i.e the headers are missing from the output. If however, I print the original from SQL, it is available. I don't accurately understand how the iterrows work because I think it is at that point that the headers got lost. Would anybody help me out with this or if there is another way out. Initially, I could do this with the SQL data being converted to csv and then I read the csv directly into reportlab to get the pdf. I, however, don't want a physical csv file in my directory that's why I decided to call the data from the databse in SQL.

```
overall_summary = self.choose_class_combo.currentText()+" " + self.choose_term_combo.currentText() + " "+ self.choose_year_combo.currentText() + " for summary"
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
str_summary = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM '" + str(overall_summary) + "'", conn)  
tdata = [] 
for index, row in str_summary.iterrows():
    rowdata = []
    BLANK=row[0]
    A1 =row[1]
    A2=row[2]
    B3=row[3]
    B4=row[4]
    B5=row[5]
    C6=row[6]
    C7=row[7]
    C8=row[8]
    D9=row[9]
    D0=row[10]
    D1=row[11]
    E2=row[12]
    X=row[13]
    Z = row[14]
    TOTAL=row[15]
    MEAN=row[16]
    GRD=row[17]
    rowdata.append(BLANK)
    rowdata.append(A1)
    rowdata.append(A2)
    rowdata.append(B3)
    rowdata.append(B4)
    rowdata.append(B5)
    rowdata.append(C6)
    rowdata.append(C7)
    rowdata.append(C8)
    rowdata.append(D9)
    rowdata.append(D0)
    rowdata.append(D1)
    rowdata.append(E2)
    rowdata.append(X)
    rowdata.append(Z)
    rowdata.append(TOTAL)
    rowdata.append(MEAN)
    rowdata.append(GRD)
    tdata.append(rowdata)
conn.commit()
conn.connect()
```

This is what is in the SQL which is the same output I want in pdf.

```
SUBJ   A  A-  B+  B  B-  C+  C  C-  D+   D  D-   E  X  Z  TOTAL MEAN   GRD
EAGLE  0   0   0  0   2   2  1   4   5  11  15   7  0  0   47  3.1064   D
HAWK   0   0   0  0   1   0  3   3   4   7  17  11  0  0   46  2.6739   D
TOTAL  0   0   0  0   3   2  4   7   9  18  32  18  0  0   93  2.8925   D
```

The output I get with the iterrows is as below.

```
EAGLE  0   0   0  0   2   2  1   4   5  11  15   7  0  0   47  3.1064   D
HAWK   0   0   0  0   1   0  3   3   4   7  17  11  0  0   46  2.6739   D
TOTAL  0   0   0  0   3   2  4   7   9  18  32  18  0  0   93  2.8925   D
```

Comment: pandas has its own native [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) command, suggest you use it. You can customize the header row if you need to. Also, there's no need to unpack each row's column as you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas `iterrows()` returns a row which is a pandas series. Where the index for the row is the column from the original dataframe. You can append the headers to `tdata` before you start the for-loop using `str_summary.columns.tolist()`.

Alternatively this may help `[str_summary.columns.tolist(),] + str_summary.values.tolist()`. What we are doing here is extracting the header and values converting them to lists and adding them together.

Comment: I greatly appreciate it. I've walked wide to get this done but couldn't. Thanks big. I can now breathe. You know I'm new in this thing, I'm trying to fix things on my own.